# How does sync.Mutex work in a concurrent Golang program

Tags: multithreading, go, mutex, goroutine

When working with a concurrent program in `Go`, we use `var mutex sync.Mutex` and then if we have to write execute some synchronized code block, we call `mutex.Lock()` and `mutex.Unlock()`. Now I have some doubts here:

1) Is there only one instance of `mutex` i.e. if `mutex` is being used for locking for operation of CodeBlockA, and at the same time some other `goroutine B` has to use it for some other CodeBlockB that also uses `mutex`, will `goroutine B` be blocked till `goroutine A` relieves `mutex`.

2) Is it possible that we can have more instances of muteness guarding their own dedicated code blocks.

Comment: show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the sample code as reference, I got the answer. if we have `var mu sync.Mutex` then Locking and Unlocking of `mu` will be serialized. It cannot be locked at the same time at two places which could be totally independent code bases. but if we have `var mu1 sync.Mutex` and `var mu2 sync.Mutex` then `mu1` and `mu2` can be locked concurrently. Following is a small program for the POC:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var mu sync.Mutex
var mu1 sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// var anotherBalance int

func code1() {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    fmt.Println("Entering code1")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Exiting code1")
}

func code2() {
    mu1.Lock()
    defer mu1.Unlock()
    fmt.Println("Entering code2")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Exiting code2")
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        code1()
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        code2()
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

And after running it,

Entering code2

Entering code1

Exiting code2

Exiting code1

real    0m1.335s

user    0m0.307s

sys 0m0.069s